# How do I display text on the terminal given line number and filepath?

Tags: bash

I have a list of lines of the form

```
file:starting linenumber:starting column number:ending linenumber:ending column number
```

That specify a region of text in given files; for example

```
/home/user/Desktop/helloworld.c:10:5:10:15
```

What is an efficient way of displaying on screen the corresponding line(s) in helloworld.c? I am pretty sure it is doable with head/tail, but am not too sure about its performance on larger files. If there is a way to also 'prettyprint' the region of text by colouring, that would be great to know about too.

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own?

Comment: `sed -n 10p /home/user/Desktop/helloworld.c` to get line 10 from the file. (or `sed -n 10,15p ...` to get lines 10-15)

Comment: The naive sed | awk (to extract line numbers) and then head -n | tail -n pipe works at least as far as displaying lines is concerned

Comment: I didn't know about the sed -n trick for range, that was good to know!

Comment: @Pororo : If the file is large, you should ideally avoid creating subprocesses for each line, which rules out your proposed head/tail solution. Even the solution suggested by DavidCRankin with one `sed` process per line could be expensive. Can one file occur several  times in the input file? I would then in a first step sort the file, so that identical files occur in groups. Then I would read the file, and for each set of input lines belonging to the same file, I would combine the ranges, open the file and get the respective lines. I wouldn't do this in bash, though.

Comment: I bit the bullet and passed the file to python to parse, which builds the list of sed commands to issue  (or opens the file if multiple regions of text are needed, which would make multiple sed commands expensive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a single line of the format `file:startRow:startCol:endRow:endCol` use the following bash function to print the referenced lines and highlight the referenced text:

```
highlight() {
    IFS=: read -r file srow scol erow ecol <<< "$1"
    shl=$'\033[31m' # start highlight, in this case red text
    ehl=$'\033[0m'  # end highlight, in this case normal text
    sed -n "$erow s/./&$ehl/$ecol;$srow s/./$shl&/$scol;$srow,$erow p;$erow q" "$file"
}
```

Example usage:

```
seq -w 1 10000 > file
highlight file:2:4:5:1
```

prints

[image: output: highlighted text]

To process a list of / file with multiple `file:startRow:startCol:endRow:endCol` use the function inside a loop:

```
IFS= read -r line; do
    highlight "$line"
done < list
```

This is not the most efficient approach, since the same file might be read multiple times. However, it probably is efficient enough. I doubt you would notice any delays, even with a lot of large files.

Comment: This works as long as the start and end lines are different. 
I added a check for that to highlight which 'seems' to work

Comment: @Pororo Good observation! The problem was that the first two `sed` commands of the form `$row s/./&$hl/$col` count characters to insert the escape sequences for highlighting. The start sequence was inserted before the end sequence. If on the same line, the command for inserting the end sequence then counted the start sequence too and therefore inserted the end sequence at the wrong place. I fixed the command by inserting the end sequence first.